# How to programatically select an option from MaterializeCSS's select?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I initialized the select with `materialize_select()` but I want to switch the currently selected option via code. Re-ordering and re-initializing the list both seems silly and would ruin the order of the list (which I would like to preserve).

For example I have a select with options: `A`, `B`, `C`

`A` is currently selected but I want to select `B`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you do is, in my case through Jquery , select the value that you want and then select Initialize.
Look:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[id$='idSelect'] option[value=1]").attr("selected", true);
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

I leave an example: [Example Select](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivRnDWrciMueEaGidHmc)

Comment: Perfect!

I actually discovered this worked from a co-worker an hour ago as well.
Too bad it isn't explicitly stated in their documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: in the above example, **$('#cmb').val( '1' )** also works when setting the option.